# Typing out columns vertically imacro Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube, imacros

Specifications:

```
Firefox 38.0.6, imacros 8.9.7, Windows 10 64-bit OS
```

What my script does:

> My code that I specify here is part that adds a comment on a YouTube
> video.

Issue:

> I'm trying to make it type out the comments as rows, so one column
> from comment text file will add to each video. I'm encountering an issue where
> the script only types out the first column, and doesn't type out other columns inside of the comment box on the
> YouTube videos.

Can someone help me?

```
var Comment = "";
Comment += "CODE:" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 5" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !DATASOURCE Comments.txt" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n";
Comment += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n";
Comment += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
Comment += "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"#contenteditable-root\" BUTTON=0" + "\n";
Comment += "EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=\"#contenteditable-root\" CHARS={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
Comment += "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";
Comment += "TAG POS=3 TYPE=TP-YT-PAPER-BUTTON ATTR=ID:button" + "\n";  
Comment += "WAIT SECONDS=3" + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep normal, `!LOOP` can only be =1 in your Script..., even if you have a `for` Loop, (Part of your Script not posted how you use `iimPlay()`...), your 'on-the-fly' generated Script gets re-interpreted/re-constructed/re-generated again and again from scratch upon every single Loop...

You need to implement your own Looping Mechanism when using a '.js' Script, (=> also for the `!DATASOURCE_LINE` Command), you cannot use the Built-in one with `!LOOP' which is meant to be used with "native" (= "not 'on-the-fly' generated") '.iim' Scripts...